# How to query related data from two micro services

Tags: microservices

One of the ideas behind Microservices is that they are independent. They have their own database to store the data.

For instance, let's assume that we have two Microservices: **People MS** and **Addresses MS**.

**People MS** - keeps the information about person like: names, age, addressID and e.t.c.

**Addresses MS** - keeps the information about addresses like: street, city, state, zip code e.t.c

For simplicity let's assume that relation between records is 1 to 1. One person can leave at one address only.

On UI, I would like to show a list of people and their addresses with a filter by the City.

Since I can only communicate between the MS via API, then this is bad Idea to query information from **Addresses MS** filtered by City and then use it as criteria to query information from **People MS**.

The question is what will be correct approach for that type of situations?
Does it mean that this specific data structure does not fit in Microservice paradigm and must be stored in one place together?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good example of where to draw lines when creating microservices, but it does talk about aspect that we see time and again with microservices.
You have data across two services and you need to show them on UI.
Well you need some place to aggregate the data first, and we normally do that in the BFF layer. It is another service which UI talks to directly and gets the data from (it is not good to make two(or more) calls from UI to power one view).
For aggregating like you said, it makes a get call on one service, gets a bunch of data, and based on this response calls the service two bloat the data. (This is how we normally tackle it, with individual services having SLAs two respond with stipulated time)

Now for the filters, I may not agree that it is a bad idea to query data from serviceA and use the response to get more data from serviceB.
It may be slow, agreed but it will not be bad (As this is how you would have done if you did not have power of joins). Now you need to check if you perceive it to be slow, or is it really slow. I have seen that such calls works fine for me in some cases. There is no significant latency on UI in terms of my response. But yes there may be cases where you may have lot of data to deal with, or some thing which services may have trouble caching for you, or just may you have more that two services involved, or simply put there way too much data and way too many fields to filter on.
In such cases we normally add one more layer in between that help us pull all the data together and also allow fast and efficient searches, something like elastic search./

So you have ways you can deal with these kind of a scenarios. However first thing you need to think of is how you have divided your product into services. If you got that right, you will be minimising scenarios like these. Follow it up aggregation and caching strategies and and then may be to search engines.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation. The only one concern I still have is about query data from serviceA by response from serviceB in cases when serviceB return you a 100.000 rows. I suggest you can't supply this amount of data to "WHERE field in ()" clause. Especially when you displaying the final results with Pagination by 15 records. So each page will pull over again all 100.000 rows again and again.

Comment: One option is to paginate the data you are getting from serviceB as well. requires some logic on your end. But usually if your data is this huge you will be better of with search layer. (Though tread with caution as to if this really is required)